# Remote Procedure Call (RPC) errors only thrown when a user is connected via Remote Desktop

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I'm trying to resolve the following Remote Procedure Call (RPC) error that occurs when an unattended Windows Service application attempts to create a new Excel file via Interop.

```
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE): The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Add(Object Template)
```

Here's the code throwing the exception. For context, I included a few lines before and after the culprit code.

```
' Create Excel objects
Dim objExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim objExcelBooks As Excel.Workbooks = objExcelApp.Workbooks 'This is the specific line it fails on every time.
Dim objExcelBook As Excel.Workbook = objExcelBooks.Add
Dim objExcelSheet As Excel.Worksheet = objExcelApp.ActiveSheet
```

Although this code worked without any issues for the past 7 years, this error started happening immediately upon migrating the service from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2016. Through much trial, error, and hair pulling, I finally discovered that this error is only thrown when someone is connected to the server via Remote Desktop. If no one is connected via Remote Desktop, everything works flawlessly.

What I can't figure out is why does this error only occur when someone is connected to the server via Remote Desktop?

Here are a few things I've tried so far.

- Added service account to the Administrators group.
- Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> Properties -> COM Security -> Added user to all permissions.
- Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application -> Properties -> Security -> Added user to all permissions.
- Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Windows Management and Instrumentation -> Properties -> Security -> Added user to all permissions.
- Excel -> File -> Options -> Advanced -> Checked "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)"
- Tried switching from early binding to late binding.

Comment: Don't use Excel interop to create files in servers. Use EPPlus to generate the file directly without the use of, or need for any installation of, Excel. Now is a perfect time to upgrade this code to the way it should have been done many years ago. You will probably find, if you take your code that prepares your file and dump it into a new project referencing EPPlus, that you need to change very little to get it to work; a lot of how EPP works seems modeled on how the interop version works. https://riptutorial.com/epplus

Comment: Thank you for providing this suggestion. This looks like something I would definitely enjoy experimenting with in my personal time.  
  
Unfortunately it appears an annual fee is now required for commercial purposes. Although we aren't selling the software we're creating, it's facilitating some operations within a for-profit corporation.

Although the license fees may outweigh the value added by the library in the end, I must continue exploring other solutions until I'm convinced all cost-free options have been exhausted.

Comment: A few cliches for that: Never confuse cost with value... Everything free has a cost... The guys who make it have to eat too; presumably your boss will pay you to explore other options - it might not take very long before you're paid more than the license fee so if nothing else that logic can be used to drive a business decision... Oh and Version 4 of EPPlus isn't licensed the same way version 5 is, and nuget can install any version you ask it to

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Caius Jard's suggestions, I eventually settled on [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/). It's fast, lightweight, free to use for commercial purposes, and doesn't rely on the installation of Excel or the Excel.Interop library to function. The best part is not only did it resolve my issue, fewer lines of code are required to accomplish the same things.